# I got really good help, but cannot comment yet, so how do I tell the contributer and others that the solution was right?

Tags: discussion

Basically I just joined, but cannot give my kudos to the author because I haven't got
enough points. So I am just asking? Now what?

Comment: If it’s your question, you upvote the answer, if it isn’t your question you wait until you have the reputation to upvote any contribution (a single upvote).

Comment: You should take the tour in the help section...

Comment: Was this on someone else's question/answer? Was it actually on [su] or was it on our sister site [so]? I can't help but notice you haven't actually asked anything on this site yet...

Comment: @burgi, it was migrated from SU main.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart This question was, but if you look at the OP's profile there are no posts on [su] at all but there is an answer he posted on [so]. I was trying to clarify if that was the post he was referring to.

Comment: Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I just joined, but cannot give my kudos to the author because I haven't got enough points.

Commentary thanking somebody for a helpful question or answer is considered noise.  So you shouldn't be submitting your kudos within the comment section.  If you find a question or answer helpful you should upvote it.

> So I am just asking? Now what?

You only need a single upvote to a single contribution to start upvoting helpful content.  The privilege of submitting commentary is not required to particpate.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the original question but I thought the OP was referring to the fact that upvotes aren't counted until you hit 125.

Comment: @Burgi - The author didn’t really specify what they meant.  Knowing that most users submit “Thank You” commentary, I made an educated assumption, on what the author meant